# What could i do to solve this error in typescript? "not all codes path return a value"

Tags: typescript

i am creating a application but got a moment where he gives me following error:
"not all codes path return a value". The error appears in the function's name (addValues) saying that the function must returns "Obj[] | undefined".

follow the code block below:

```
public addValues() {

        const inputValue = document.getElementById('valor') as HTMLFormElement;

        const inputNameValue = 
        document.getElementById('nome-valor') as HTMLFormElement;

        const enterChecked = document.getElementById('entrada') as HTMLFormElement;
        const leftChecked = document.getElementById('saida') as HTMLFormElement;

        if (inputValue?.length && inputNameValue?.length && (enterChecked.checked || leftChecked.checked)) {
            const list: Obj = {
                id: Math.random(),
                valor: +inputValue,
                nomeValor: String(inputNameValue),
                checked: enterChecked.checked ? enterChecked : leftChecked
            }

            if (this.valores == undefined) {
                return undefined
            }

            return this.valores = [list]
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

With your first `if` statement, you create a branch with two paths. If the expression is true, you run the code inside which has two return statements. If the expression is false, you reach the end of the function without returning any value. That's what is meant by "not all code paths return a value".

You should specify the return type of the function and return a value of that type in every branch.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is a result of all your return statements being inside your if block. You need to have a return statement following that block, otherwise, there are cases in which your function returns nothing, which violates its return value definition of either an object array or an undefined object, as you stated.